# Index of a local maximum in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that there's a similar problem which was already has answered, but mine is just a little bit different (because it returns the index of the local maximum in a list, instead of the number). So, I do just need an explanation about how should I start my code, since I have no idea about where to start. (Sorry for my English). Thanks.

```
    def maxloc(xs):
      while True:
        for i in range(len(xs)):
          if xs[i] > xs[i-1] and xs[i] > xs[i+1]:
            big = xs[i]
      return [i]
```

-x-
I've tried again, but the problem now is different. I changed some of my code and the return is always [ ]. Can't understand why. Can ou help me now that I have some code, please?

```
    def maxloc(xs):
     l1 = []
     for i in range(1, len(xs)-1):
       if xs[i] > xs[i-1] and xs[i] > xs[i+1]:
          l1.append(i)
       return [l1]
     return []
```

Comment: Wouldn't the code from the similar problem be a start? Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is more about "I've done this and I'm stuck" than "no idea where to start"

Comment: I suggest you learn more about python and look at similar questions, and if you still have no idea where to start, please try a different question and come back to this later. We here at Stack Overflow can help with fixing your code or providing alternatives, but you can't expect us to help you without you trying anything at all.

Comment: @Zev  I'm really sorry if Stack Overflow is more about that, but I'm new here and I'm a beginner at programming, so it is really about "having no idea". Just need an explanation.

Comment: Here's a start: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

Comment: Related/dupe: [Finding local maxima/minima with Numpy in a 1D numpy array](//stackoverflow.com/q/4624970)

Comment: Unfortunately, being new to programming does not change the rules of SO, which you should check out.  Please read [ask], as well as go to the [help/on-topic] to learn which types of topics are on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Faming_Dorito I made some code.. but I think it's s bad, that I preferred not to put at all. But, here it is (and I'm going to edit the post)
def maxloc(xs):
    while True:
        for i in range(len(xs)):
            if xs[i] > xs[i-1] and xs[i] > xs[i+1]:
                big = xs[i]
        return [i]

Comment: @Chrisz I'm going to edit the post and put my code there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finds the maximum value and then finds its first occurence in the given list

```
def max_index(my_list)

   max_value = max(my_list)
   max_index = my_list.index(max_value)

return max_index
```

Here's the expected behaviour.

```
> list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
> max_index(list)
> 3
```

Comment: I got it (and those case I know what to do). The problem is, imagine the list [1, 3, 2, 5, 4], then there are to maxims, 3 and 5, because 3>1, 3>2, 5>2 and 5>4. So, it is supposed to return [1, 3]. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wait so what is the behaviour you're looking for, you want to specify the amount of maximums you want found?

Comment: Yes, the indexes of the maxims. Thanks for the help, @PEREZje